# Using DecimalFormat

Tags: android, decimalformat

I want to create price format

I fond it this code in internet by searching

```
/*
/ other code
*/ 
// create price format
DecimalFormat formatData = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

/*
/ other code
*/ 

Menu_price.add(Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("Price"))));
```

or

```
Menu_price = Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("Price")));

/*
/ other code
*/
```

It works, but if i have a number like 20, it gives me this:

20.0

and I want this:

20

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Just change `DecimalFormat("#.##")` to `DecimalFormat("#");` for that case.

Or use

```
double prizeInDouble = menu.getDouble("Price");

Menu_prize = prizeInDouble.intValue();
```

Or do

```
Menu_prize = (int) prizeInDouble;
```